# Query to populate MySQL database with several million rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. The first one is named "weights" and contains around 250.000 rows:

mid / weight

1 / 3

2 / 12

3 / 7

The second one is called "recipient" and has around 2 million rows and is this way:

mid / weight

1 / -

1 / -

1 / -

2 / -

I am trying to populate it with the "weight" information from the table "weights" and I am using this query:

```
UPDATE recipient A
SET weight =
  (SELECT weight
   FROM recipient B
   WHERE B.mid = A.mid)
```

The query seems to work for the first few rows, but it seems that 2 million is too much. I am running MAMP on my mac. How would you advise me to do?

Comment: What makes you think 2 million is too much?

Comment: I have used this query in the past and it updates 250K rows with no problems. I am trying with 2 millions and let my computer "work" for 30 minutes and it doesn't update the entire table.

Comment: What about using a join instead of a subquery?

Comment: do you have an index on 'mid' in both tables? do it in ranges. say where mid<100000,   then again mid>=100000 and mid<200000, etc, depending on your values

Comment: Would you have a link describing how to do that? I am not sure I understand (beginner here)

Comment: Your query updates from the same table to itself. Why?

Comment: Andreas is right, no subqueries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do suspect that you have no indexes defined on your table.

```
UPDATE  recipient A
        INNER JOIN weight B
            ON B.mid = A.mid
SET     a.weight = b.weight
```

for faster performance, make `weight.mid` primary key and reference `recipient.mid` on it.